# Datagrid Binding Using MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm facing an issue in datagrid binding using mvvm on two different places. Headers of my datagrid (xaml) is:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" AlternationCount="2" Background="White" RowHeight="28" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Lavender" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Lavender"
           VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Name="MainGrid" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
           CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Configurations, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

which clealy says

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Configurations, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

In my viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewerConfiguration> Configurations
{
    get { return m_tasks; }
    set { m_tasks = value; OnPropertyChanged("Configurations"); }
}
```

The data that in the list is shown properly on the view but the problem is with the insert and delete (even it updates successfully).
I have a function which inserts an item in the Configuration object

```
private void Refresh()
{
    List<ViewerConfiguration> newlyAddedFiles = GetConfigurations();
    foreach (ViewerConfiguration config in newlyAddedFiles)
    {
        Configurations.Add(config);
    }
}
```

and removes like:

```
 Configurations.Remove(configuration);
```

The problem is really with the insert and delete. On debugging there is no exception and it successfully deletes from collection too but UI doesn't get a notification. Any guesses why is this behavior?

**Additionally:**
I have an event trigger just under the datagrid:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RenderPdf}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MainGrid}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and I'm calling Refresh function from the constructor of ViewModel just to see if it works or not.

Comment: are your deletes and adds generating an event?  I doubt it...

Comment: @TMcKeown it does if it's an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Post the full code. Your question is unclear. The code you are currently showing doesn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: @T Mckeown Yes they are working. As i said, it even deletes from the collection successfully and i can see the count decremented as well.

Comment: @HighCore, would adding/deleting from the Observable collection bubble up to his class?  I guess I'm not seeing where he's listening to those events, I see the setter generates events on the `Configuration` property.

Comment: @AliBaig, i understand that the delete is occurring but you're not getting an event generated right?

Comment: I tried updating the question. Its simple enough that I have bind'ed my datagrid's itemssource to an observable collection in the viewmodel, it reads the data successfully and updates it too. 

One thing that i can guess go wrong is, the buttons that are generating the events (add/delete/update) are in other Grid in the Window but they are updating the same collection so that shouldn't matter a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue i was having. There were basically two problems. In the getter of my Configurations, i was return a new observable collection after sorting and filtering the previous one.
The second main problem:

```
 'This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread'
```

That was my best guess and i changed my refresh function to:

```
 private void Refresh()
    {
        try
        {
            List<ViewerConfiguration> newlyAddedFiles = GetConfigurations();
            //should not update on other thread than on main thread
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate()
            {
                foreach (ViewerConfiguration config in newlyAddedFiles)
                {
                    Configurations.Add(config);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Now, its working.
Thanks